# Get related rows in one table using a table with relations

Tags: php, sql, join

I have two tables. One stores the content records, the other one stores the relations between the content-records.

```
table "content"             table "relations"  
+---+-----+------+------+   +---------+----------+  
|id |num  |text  |value |   |id_local |id_foreign|  
+---+-----+------+------+   +---------+----------+  
|1  |111  |aaa   |12345 |   |2        |3         |  
+---+-----+------+------+   +---------+----------+  
|2  |222  |bbb   |23456 |   |2        |5         |  
+---+-----+------+------+   +---------+----------+  
|3  |333  |ccc   |34567 |   |4        |1         |  
+---+-----+------+------+   +---------+----------+  
|4  |444  |ddd   |45678 |   |2        |1         |  
+---+-----+------+------+   +---------+----------+  
|5  |555  |eee   |56789 |   |3        |6         |  
+---+-----+------+------+   +---------+----------+  
|6  |666  |fff   |67890 |   |4        |5         |  
+---+-----+------+------+   +---------+----------+
```

Reading table "relations"

id_local = id of record in content ("parent")
id_foreign = id of record in content that is related to id_local ("child")

I want all relations for content.num = 222 in the order they were entered in table "relations". The result should look like this:

```
result  
+-----+------+  
|num  |value |  
+-----+------+  
|333  |34567 |  
+-----+------+  
|555  |56789 |  
+-----+------+  
|111  |12345 |  
+-----+------+
```

I tried some JOINs but never got this result.

Please, does anybody know how I can get this result?

**Additional question:**

If I want to output the content.value=23456 of the "parent"-record with all "child"-records, how should the query look like?

```
result 2
+-----+------+--------+  
|num  |value | p-value|  
+-----+------+--------+
|333  |34567 | 23456  |  
+-----+------+--------+  
|555  |56789 | 23456  |    
+-----+------+--------+  
|111  |12345 | 23456  |  
+-----+------+--------+
```

Comment: Which database are you using?  (MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, ...)

Comment: Sorry, the datavase is MySQL-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i guess it is weird method but;

```
SELECT num, value
FROM content
WHERE id IN (
  SELECT id_foreign
  FROM relations
  WHERE id_local = ( SELECT id FROM content WHERE num = '222' )
  )
  AND num = '222' -- Additional answer
```

Comment: Wrong. `id_local` would be `2` and not `222`

Comment: This gives me an error-code

Subquery returns more than one row

Comment: if your num field is not an integer then use `'222'`

Comment: I added an additional question. Please have a look at it.

Comment: you can add end of the query `AND num = '222'`; look at my answer again

Answer (score 0):

```
select  c2.num
,       c2.value
from    content c1
join    relations r
on      c1.id = r.id_local
join    content c2
on      r.id_foreign = c2.id
where   c1.num = 222
```

[Example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a73b5/1/0)

Comment: This gives me a result listing content.num, content.value for content.id=2 3 times (parent-record), but not the three related records.

Comment: The query does produce the 3 related records on SQL Fiddle

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a `join` as being required here.

All you need is the ID of the "parent" record.. in this case it's `2`.

`Select num, value from content where id in (select id_foreign where id_local=2)`

If you don't know the ID, but only the `num` value...

`Select num, value from content where id in (select id_foreign where id_local=(select id from content where num='222'))`

Comment: Thank you very much. So many good answers just after pressing ENTER for the question.

Comment: This gives me an error-code "Subquery returns more than one row"